# Conjugate of centralizer gives all diagonal matrices implies distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable $n\times n$-matrix. Assume that the set of matrices commuting with $A$ is simultaneosly diagonalizable. Why does this imply that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue.

Without loss of generality, assume that $A$ is diagonal, with like eigenvalues grouped together (that is, apply an appropriate change of basis otherwise). Suppose furthermore that the repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ comes first.

Now, $A$ has the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda I & 0\\ 0 & D}
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix of some size, and $D$ is diagonal.  Note that $A$ commutes with any matrix 
$$
M = \pmatrix{B&0\\0&0}
$$
partitioned in a similar fashion.  However, $M$ and $A$ are only simultaneously diagonalizable if $B$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

let $R$ denote the subring of $n \times n$ diagonal matrices and let $E(i,j)$ be a matrix with $e_{kl}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$

then for $D \in R$
$$
DE(i,j)=d_iE(i,j)
$$
and 
$$
E(i,j)D=d_jE(i,j)
$$
if any pair of elements of $D$ are equal, then there is a non-diagonal matrix that commutes with $D$, contrary to hypothesis